# Dynamics MetaDataService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, metadata, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to retrieve a list of PickList values to bind to a form. From what I've read I need to use the MetaData service, but despite adding a standard web reference to http://myserver/mscrmservices/2007/metadataservice.asmx?WSDL, the added namespace does not contain MetaDataService . I have the SDK, but from what I can tell the MetaDataService should be part of the generated web reference code.

I need the **?wsdl** on the end of the URL or I get a 401, and I don't understand why the generated namespace does not contain MetadataService.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding a web reference for the service and tinkering with the settings. I'm not entirely sure how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ?wsdl at the end of any normal WCF web service will give you (if available) the WSDL file describing the service.

Dynamics CRM has different endpoints depending on the version 3, 4, 2011 and for CRM 4, the recommended endpoint to use has the organization name as part of the URI.

Also note that the need for metadata can be provided in many ways. you can point Visual studio to the URI and generate a proxy class, or you can use the dlls that follow the SDK.